# Getting a strange parse error for JSON uploaded to Google Cloud storage

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So, I'm doing some testing of google cloud storage access. I am trying to manually upload a json file (via the console) that I will programmatically change. But Google doesn't seem to like my json file. The beginning of the file looks like:

```
{
  'mlsid': "MD-BRIGHT",
  'mlsno': "1000000300",
  'maxres': "2x",
  'modified': "20180201133459",
  'count': 28,
  'photos': {
    'org': [
    {
      'uri': "https://storage.googleapis.com/idx-photos-gs.ihouseprd.com/MD-BRIGHT/1000000300/org/000.jpg",
      'width': 625,
      'height': 768
    },
 . . .
```

Which looks correct to me, but when I try to open the file in a window from the GCS control panel, it displays this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{    'mlsid': "MD-BRIGHT"
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

I mean, isn't 'mlsid' a string? I have tried it with both single and double quotes. Quite baffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid JSON requires double-quotes and not single-quotes for keys and strings.

```
{
  "mlsid": "MD-BRIGHT",
```